# Which is better: "On first reading" vs. "At first reading"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

In the context of a section in a technical document that describes several topics, one of which is essential and others can be skipped, which of  the following is better?

> You can skip the others on first reading.

vs

> You can skip the others at first reading.

Comment: [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+first+reading%2Cat+first+reading&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) suggests either is fine but there are a lot of irrelevant results, e.g. the first reading of legislation in Congress and stuff like "on first reading Shakespeare", so I don't think that can be taken as conclusive evidence. I don't think it matters though.

Comment: There's just as much "noise" with "at first reading" in that it can refer to taking measurements and presenting legislation.  My sense is that *at first reading* in your context is somewhat dated, and *on first reading* is the more contemporary choice.

Comment: **upon first reading** would also be viable.

Comment: Where do the examples come from? Either might work grammatically, but neither seems plausible… less so if you go with Edwin's Answer, in which it would be not only wrong, but verging on criminal to skip anything.